# Decoding wireless captures / filters on Linux

Tags: linux, tcpdump, tshark

I am trying to filter a capture file that was captured by a remote AP. If i pull the file to my laptop i can open in Wireshark decode as peekremote and create the display filter EAPOL to get the packets i want.

However i have about 100Gbs of data on the capture server and i would like to know if i can do this with Tshark or other tool on the linux server directly

Something like this but this just copies the file I just want to output the files to the EAP traffic. Does anyone have any thoughts I am not use to dealing with tshark.

tshark -r capture-18.pcap -J eapol -w test.pcap

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after a bit of playing about I worked this out. It was a simple `-Y` filter

```bash
tshark -r in.pcap -Y eapol -w out.pcap
```